# cusp sparse matrix to be used in struct in C

Tags: c, cuda, sparse-matrix, cusp-library

I am using the [cusp](http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/) library with CUDA to use sparse matrix. Can't I use it in a `struct` in C like:

```
  #include <cusp/coo_matrix.h>
  #include <cusp/multiply.h>
  #include <cusp/print.h>
  #include <cusp/transpose.h>
  struct Cat{
         int id;
         cusp::coo_matrix<int, double, cusp::host_memory> A(2,100,10);
  };
  int main(){
  }
```

I am getting the errors:

```
try.cu(7): error: expected a type specifier
try.cu(7): error: expected a type specifier
try.cu(7): error: expected a type specifier
```

What is the correct way to use it in a `struct` so that I can have array of such structures?

Comment: Line `6` of your example is `int id;`  That wouldn't cause a type specifier error.  Please post the exact code you're trying to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That piece of code `coo_matrix` looks suspiciously like a C++ template.
If so, provide your `Cat struct` with constructor and initialize A there:

```
struct Cat {
  int id;
  cusp::coo_matrix<int, double, cusp::host_memory> A;
  Cat(): id(0), A(2,100,10) {}
}
```

Comment: @parallel - this is C++. class and struct data members can only be types, calling a constructor as part of a data declaration is illegal.